# Escaping mysql without single quotes?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

In Codeigniter/PHP I'm having trouble escaping the instances of $table in the SQL statement below.

When I try any of the methods like the ones used at the end of the query they don't work because of the single quotes.

Is there any methods or changes any one can recommend in this situation?

Thanks in advance for any help.

MYSQL statement:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM $table INNER JOIN resumes ON resumes.resume_id = $table.resume_id AND resumes.user_id = ".$this->db->escape($user_id)." AND $table.$field = ?";
```

Comment: Where do you get the `$table` variable from?

Comment: @zerkms, The $table variable comes from a controller, not user input, don't know if that makes the question somewhat irrelevant?

Comment: @jsuissa: if it comes from trusted source (like controller, because you hardcoded it there) - then you don't need to quote it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should **never** accept the table name or column name as a user input.

But in case you have no other alternatives - the only solution is white-lists

So you create an array with all the allowed table names to be used like

```
$valid_tables = array('t1', 'table2');
```

and then check if the `$table` exists in that array:

```
if (in_array($table, $valid_tables)) {
    // everything is fine
} else {
    // something is wrong
}
```

Comment: thanks -- in this case it's from a trusted source, but as a generality what you answered is very helpful. Thanks again.